# running kivy shows black screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm starting in Kivy and this small example when running it opens the screen but everything is black nothing else is seen

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random

class RanWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RanWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def generate_number(self):
      self.rlabel.text = str(random.randint(0, 2000))

class RandomNumber(App):
    def build(self):
        return RanWindow()

if __name__=="__main__":
  RandomNumber().run()
```

random.kv

```
<RanWindow>:
    rlabel: rlabel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Random Number"
            font_size: 30
            color: 0, 0.62, 0.96

        Label:
            id: rlabel
            text: "_"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: "Generate"
            font_size: 15
            on_press: root.generate_number()
```

does not show any error

Comment: I found no issues with your code, make sure that `kivy` is properly installed with all its dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, as I didn't notice the file name (I used method `Builder.load_string`). Check the installation after checking John Anderson's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `random.kv` file is not loaded. You need to either add:

```
Builder.load_file('random.kv')
```

to your code. Or change the name of `random.kv` to `randomnumber.kv`.